# getifaddrs heap-buffer-overflow in 32 bit app compiled from a 64 bit BSD system

Tags: c++, clang, freebsd, address-sanitizer

I'm facing an odd issue while debugging my program with Clang's AddressSanitizer. The exact same code works on another 64 bit system but gives a heap-buffer-overflow error on the other.

Both machines run the same operating system (BSD 10 64 bit) with the same toolchain etc, except that the one that works is compiled as 64 bit (so a 64bit app running on a 64bit system) and the one giving issues is compiled as a 32 bit app on a 64 bit system.

There's not much code to show as the issue resides in just this one call:

```
struct ifaddrs * ifAddrStruct = NULL;
getifaddrs(&ifAddrStruct);
```

And this is the stacktrace dumped by ASan:

```
==19706==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow on address 0x2e603e78 at pc 0x0832bbb2 bp 0xffff3288 sp 0xffff2e60
READ of size 256 at 0x2e603e78 thread T0
    #0 0x832bbb1 in memcpy /home/dim/llvm-3.8.0/final/llvm.src/projects/compiler-rt/lib/asan/asan_interceptors.cc:438:3
    #1 0x2bdbed49 in getifaddrs (/usr/lib32//libc.so.7+0xecd49)

0x2e603e78 is located 0 bytes to the right of 1528-byte region [0x2e603880,0x2e603e78)
allocated by thread T0 here:
    #0 0x8337df0 in __interceptor_malloc /home/dim/llvm-3.8.0/final/llvm.src/projects/compiler-rt/lib/asan/asan_malloc_linux.cc:52:3
    #1 0x2bdbe87f in getifaddrs (/usr/lib32//libc.so.7+0xec87f)
    #2 0x8325799 in getifaddrs /home/dim/llvm-3.8.0/final/llvm.src/projects/compiler-rt/lib/asan/../sanitizer_common/sanitizer_common_interceptors.inc:4368:13
    #3 0x8f1a443 in GetIPInfo(void) ...../src/config.cpp:243:2
    #4 0x8f22837 in config_init(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) ...../src/config.cpp:329:7
    #5 0xadf1cf9 in start(int, char**) (app+0xadf1cf9)
    #6 0xade5a6c in main (app+0xade5a6c)
    #7 0x82db629 in _start1 (app+0x82db629)
    #8 0x82db4e7 in _start (app+0x82db4e7)
    #9 0x0  (<unknown module>)

SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow /home/dim/llvm-3.8.0/final/llvm.src/projects/compiler-rt/lib/asan/asan_interceptors.cc:438:3 in memcpy
Shadow bytes around the buggy address:
  0x45cc0770: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x45cc0780: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x45cc0790: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x45cc07a0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x45cc07b0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
=>0x45cc07c0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00[fa]
  0x45cc07d0: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x45cc07e0: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x45cc07f0: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x45cc0800: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x45cc0810: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
```

I'm using the exact same CFLAGS on both machines, same compiler (Clang 3.8), same library versions. Been looking on Google and on StackOverflow for a while but this seems to be an isolated case as I couldn't find anyone else having my very same issue.

Hoping someone knows more on this matter.

Thanks in advance to whoever can help me out.

Edit1: I realized just now that I've been using Clang 3.8.1 on the system where everything works fine (64bit app in 64bit system) while the other one still had 3.8.0. I'm not sure but at this point I suspect it's a bug in the compiler. Upgrading to 3.8.1 now, with all related 32 bit libraries (ASan etc), will report back when I have some news.

Comment: This is a buffer overflow in BSD's getifaddrs. Have you tried [reporting](https://www.freebsd.org/support/bugreports.html) to BSD folks?

Comment: No, I haven't. Besides as already mentioned, it works on the same OS version running as 64 bit, but not on as a 32 bit app (on 64bit env). Also, the same executable compiled with gcc 5.0 under FreeBSD 9.3 64bit works just fine as well (running as 32 bit). I'm not sure if this is, therefore, a system bug or just a compiler bug or broken libraries..

Comment: "I'm not sure if this is, therefore, a system bug or just a compiler bug or broken libraries" - the overflow happens entirely in getifaddrs (both malloc and memcpy happen there) so your code isn't really invoked so it's unlikely to be a compiler bug. Ideally you could debug `getifaddrs` to see what's going on as I'm not sure FreeBSD folks would accept ASan reports without any investigation.